# Create local libraries from Android Project with module

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libraries

I have Android Project. It is include two modules. (Dlib, OpenCV) I have custom class view which work with camera. How i can create lib? (.arr or .jar)

Now I have lid with class, but how I can add to lib module Dlib and OpenCV

**EDIT**
My gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments "-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=TRUE", "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang", "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release"
                cppFlags "-std=c++11", "-frtti", "-fexceptions"
            }
        }
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile project(':openCVLibrary320')
    compile project(':dlib')
}
```

Comment: post your gradle

Comment: @BhuvaneshBs added